# Check mailWindow through mailEntryId is open or not

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, mapi, outlook-redemption

I open Outlook mail using Outlook Redemption(http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) `rdoMail.DoAction(rdoMessageAction.maOpen)`. How I can check open this mail or not when I try open it next time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Inspectors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868935.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of the Application class from the Outlook object model returns an `Inspectors` collection object that contains the `Inspector` objects representing all open inspectors.

You may iterate over all items in the collection and check the [CurrentItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869722.aspx) property which returns an Object representing the current item being displayed in the inspector.

Then you can check out the `EntryID` property of the displayed item.